# How is the statement A is N% faster than B interpreted?

Tags: meaning

If A takes 50 seconds and B takes 100 seconds, is it right to say that A is 50% faster or 100% faster? Is either interpretation acceptable or one is more usual?

Comment: I'd say A is 100% faster. If you take another example without the number 50 it might be clearer.  If A takes 30 seconds and B takes 60 seconds, then A is twice as fast as B or 100% faster. But I've a feeling this might be considered maths and not English.

Comment: A goes 2 units per second while B only goes 1 unit per second.  So A is 100% faster.  (Though it would be more normal to say that A is "twice as fast".)

Comment: It is seldom interpreted the same way twice, so technical people avoid that construction like the plague. Does it make sense that 100% faster, or 200% faster means twice as fast? Identify the reference quantity explicitly, and use a zero baseline rather than start at the speed of the first and count up from there. A's speed is 200% of B's speed - no *faster, greater, better, pricier,* or any other *-er*.

Answer (score 0):

You'd say that A is 100% faster than B, while B is 50% as fast as A.

In general, when you describe A relative to B, you use the percentage of B that must be added or subtracted to B to get A.

Some people also would say that B is 50% slower than A. But many people object to this form, because we don't measure slowness, we measure speed. I've also heard people describe this as "twice as slow"; but if you interpret that similarly to "twice as fast", you'd expect it to mean the speed is zero. In practice, the meaning is usually clear.

Comment: Your *A*s and *B*s seem to be mixed up (A is faster than B).

Comment: You're right, I was thinking "A goes 50 MPH" vs "B goes 100 MPH".

Comment: I also read it that way first.